# Mysql query array

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

1 - hotels[id,name,extras] ( name of hotels with column extras which I've select for each one)

2 - extras[id,name] ( here's the extras of hotel like wifi,tv,swim... )

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$hotels_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hotels` WHERE `name`='$name'") or die (mysql_error());
$hotels_row = mysql_fetch_array($hotels_q);
$id = $hotels_row['id'];    
$extras = explode(",", $hotels_row['extras']);

$ekstras_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `extras` order by id") or die(mysql_error());
            While($ekstras_row = mysql_fetch_array($ekstri_q)){
                $eid = $ekstras_row['id'];
                $ename = $ekstri_row ['name'];
            echo '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" name="extras['.$eid.'][]" value="'.$ename.'"';
            if (in_array($eid, $ekstras)) echo'checked';            
                echo'/>'.$ename.'</li></ul>';
```

Problem is here extras_q displays all entries with checked ones from table, but I want only to display only checked items!

Comment: Is the id column in extras a hotel id?

Comment: @DarshanMehta because table will be huge!

Comment: you need a third table to join hotels to extras with (hotel_id, extra_id). also stop using mysql depreciated API and your open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: `mysql_*` has been deprecated and is no longer supported. It's best coding practices to switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: @Dagon looks like the extras are in the hotels table as a CSV column :(

Comment: @Dagon What to include inside third table ?

Comment: @1mnumb1 as i said above: *(hotel_id, extra_id)*

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes they comma seperated wtih implode!

Comment: @1mnumb1 If you had the many-to-many relationship that Dagon is referring to, you could join these tables together and accomplish this with one query.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've inserting into hotels table to column as $extras = implode(",", (array)(isset($_POST['extras']) ? $_POST['extras'] : null));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're storing your extra IDs in one column as a comma separated string, I think you should be able to do this by *not* exploding that value, and then using the CSV string as an `IN` criteria in your second query.

```
//...
$extras = $hotels_row['extras']; // don't explode

// Use IN with the $extras CSV here
$ekstras_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `extras` 
                          WHERE id IN ($extras) ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you are able to modify your database, you can instead create a many-to-many relationship between hotels and extras by adding a table to join those two items together instead of using a CSV column as you currently are. This can make it easier to write queries to select the related records.

If you add a third table `hotel_extras` with columns `hotel_id` and `extra_id`, you can insert one row for each extra that each hotel has. For example, if the hotel with id 1 has several different extras, its entries in that table would look like this:

```
table: hotel_extras
_______________________
| hotel_id | extra_id |
=======================
|    1     |     1    |
|    1     |     3    |
|    1     |     4    |
-----------------------
```

Here is an example using PDO of how you could query data from a setup like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT e.id, e.name
 FROM hotels h
    INNER JOIN hotel_extras he ON h.id = he.hotel_id
    INNER JOIN extras e ON he.extra_id = e.id
 WHERE h.`name` = ?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_GET['name']);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $eid = $row['id'];
    $ename = $row['name'];
    '<li><input type="checkbox" name="extras['.$eid.'][]" value="'.$ename.'" checked/>'.$ename.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: I've got  Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in this line  - if (in_array($eid, $ekstras)) echo'checked';

Comment: Oh, if you do it this way, you shouldn't need that line. Since you're only getting the ones from the database that are associated with that hotel, they'll all be checked anyway, so you can just include the `checked` in your HTML every time.

Comment: Yes works! But if I make with third table to join others, how need to looks query.

Comment: in the long run a third table is a MUCH better idea

Comment: Ok how to explode each one with comma. If I echo "$ename, "; at the end keeps comma.If use explode in $ename - got array to string convertion?

Comment: @Dagon I very much agree.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for bigggg query :)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Can be inserted into table extras_id column id with CSV ?

Comment: No, in order for the join to work, there must be one row for each extra_id.

Comment: @Don't Panic's Ok I understand.About first query how to echoing each one seperated by comma?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand exactly what you're asking. What is it you want to echo separated by commas?